# Serial communication in Qt creator

Tags: qt, serial-port, serial-communication

I came across the following error described below, how can I rectify this sort of error and why does this error is generated?

> QIODEVICE::write:device not open

( the com port are also not visible in device manager)

Is this some sort of system error ?

Comment: Please include some code leading to this error in your question. There are multiple `QIODevices` so this error alone does not tell us enough. Please also [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have using just Qt then use QSerialPort otherwise you can use windows API  createfile(), readfile() ,writefile() in Windows Platform.
You can take other information in:
http://support.microsoft.com/KB/115831
or this post in Stackoverflow:
[Open a COM port in C++ with number higher that 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775185/open-a-com-port-in-c-with-number-higher-that-9)