# RFID reader Serial port

Tags: rfid

Hi i dont know if this is right to post here but i dont know where to go. i have an RFID Reader this one http://www.stronglink-rfid.com/en/rfid-readers/sl500.html and already installed the driver from that website. the problem is the port is on com23 which is i think is not valid.

[image]

can somebody help me out?

> Im using win7 64bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a COM port in C++ with number higher that 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775185/open-a-com-port-in-c-with-number-higher-that-9)

Comment: How am i going to fix this without a code i already reinstall.

Comment: SO is for programming related questions - if you have issues with a high-numbered COM interface as the **user** of a program you should ask this question on [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 0):

If your software program supports configurable COM port number, I think it is nothing wrong with high-numbered COM port. If your software program accepts only certain COM port numbers (I have seen some S/W that provide list of predefined COM port number), you can just right click the record and change it to any un-used COM port you want.

Answer (score 0):

Seem ok. Your RFID device uses this port to communicate.